# How can I test Lazy loaded component using jest + enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-lazy-load

In my react application I have implemented Lazy loading using `React.lazy(() => import("..."))`. But I am not able to implement the testcase that will support Lazy load.

**Without `React.lazy(() => import("..."))` my testcases are working fine but only with `React.lazy`it is not working.**

Please help in this.

auth.jsx

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const SignIn = React.lazy(() => import("../../components/SignIn/SignIn"));

const Authentication = props => {
    return (
        <div id="wrapper" className="bg-gradient-primary">
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn} />
                </Switch>
            </Suspense>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Authentication;
```

And here is my test code.

auth.spec.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Authentication from "./Authentication";
import SignIn from "../../components/SignIn/SignIn";

describe("Authentication", () => {
    let component;
    beforeEach(() => {
        component = shallow(<Authentication />);
    });
    it("should render", () => {
        expect(component.find("#wrapper")).toHaveLength(1);
    });

    it('should render "SignIn"', () => {
        const routeEl = component.find('Route[path="/sign-in"]');
        expect(routeEl.first().prop("component")).toBe(SignIn);
    });

});
```

When I will run my testcases, I am getting bellow error

```
 expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

 Expected: [Function SignIn]
 Received: {"$$typeof": Symbol(react.lazy), "_ctor": [Function anonymous], "_result": null, "_status": -1}
```

Comment: This is likely not possible with enzyme, see here (https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2212)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Is there any way that I can mock `React.lazy`?